# Insert image into modern text webpart not possible

Tags: sharepoint-online, web-part, modern-experience, sitepages, text-webpart

On Microsoft's official documentation it is described that you can insert images directly into the Text Web Part and do not need an Image Web Part.

Unfortunately this does not work with my SharePoint Online. But this is up to date. Do I have to make a setting somewhere?

See here. This does not work:

[image]

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/add-text-tables-and-images-to-your-page-with-the-text-web-part-729c0aa1-bc0d-41e3-9cde-c60533f2c801

Answer (score 2):

Microsoft is adding the ability to paste inline images into the Text web part so that images can be closer to text and so that text can wrap around images.

[Microsoft 365 Roadmap ID 85584](https://www.microsoft.com/en-ww/microsoft-365/roadmap?filters=&searchterms=85584)

This feature is currently rolling out to [Targeted release tenants](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/admin/manage/release-options-in-office-365?view=o365-worldwide) & soon will be available for all tenants (standard release/GA)

So, Either you have to set up targeted release for yourself/your tenant (see above link) or wait until standard release/GA of this new feature.

[image]